# How to serve photo gallery update to Googlebot?

Tags: seo, redirect, bots, googlebot

How to set up redirections when photo galleries on a site have been updated?

Some of the photos were removed, so the Googlebot gets 404 for now. But there are no substitute for those old photos. There are some new, similar photos in the same topic, but not the same.

Should I redirect the request somewhere? E.g. log gets flooded by requests to `/images/some.jpg`, so redirect this to (where?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a two-pronged approach:

**1) Update Google's Index of Your Site**

Claim your site via [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/), and request a crawl of your site. This should remove most of the removed images from their index, and reduce the number of 404 Errors visitors to your site and now getting.
[Remove a page or site from Google's search results](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734)

**2) Update your 404 Error Page**

If you do not already have a customised 404 page, think about creating one, which can then contain a message advising the user that the link has been changed and directing them to your home page and/or search page (trying to keep them in your site rather than simply closing the browser window.
[Google Search for Custom 404 page articles](http://www.google.com.au/search?tbo=1&prmdo=1&q=htaccess%20custom%20404%20page)

Answer (score 0):

simple answer: if a ressource is gone (i.e.: an html page, an image file) the right response is "HTTP 410 Gone" (HTTP 404 is also ok)

google will kick this ressource out of its index.

there is no benefit for SEO if you do an HTTP redirect to anywhere else. there is no user experience benefit if you redirect them somewhere else (a custom HTTP 404 / 410 page has a better effect)